# Secure way of accessing SQL Stored Procedures from Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, sql-injection

I am mid 'Pen Test' and trying to find the "most secure" way to use `Entity Framework Core` to Stored Procedures. You would think it would be obvious, but please read on.

**Background**

Using [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) on using Raw SQL and having read [Whats new in .NET Core 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0#string-interpolation-in-fromsql-and-executesqlcommand) my initial code used string interpolation (showed as safe in the 'what's new' document).

However, the Pen Test successfully managed a sql injection attack against it.

Offending code example:

```
dbResults = _datacontext.Blogs.FromSql($"myStoredProcedure @parmeter1 = {parmeter1String}");
```

So, I changed the code to use params, but they also broke through this:

```
dbResults = _datacontext.Blogs.FromSql("myStoredProcedure @parmeter1 = {0}", parmeter1String);
```

and they broke this (though maybe I wasn't cleaning enough - at least I stopped `exec`):

```
dbResults = _datacontext.Blogs.FromSql("myStoredProcedure @parmeter1 = {0}", parmeter1String.ToCleanedSqlString());
```

So is the answer to use SqlParameter (not shown in any of the above docs/examples)?

```
dbResults = _datacontext.Blogs.FromSql("myStoredProcedure @parmeter1 = {0}", new SqlParameter("@parmeter1", parmeter1String));
```

or is there a better way?

Some definitive guidance would be appreciated please.

**EDIT Following comment:**

Important addition: The stored procedure does execute dynamic sql, but that procedure is not in my application and I don't have control over it. I have to call it.

Comment: Presumably the first example is missing a leading `$"` ?  Both examples should most certainly not be vulnerable to injection, do you have an example input string that breaks the parameterization?  Does the underlying SP use the given  param in dynamic SQL in any way?

Comment: Any of these will bind command parameter, so I don't see how the sql injection attack against it succeeds, except if your stored procedure is using the `@parmeter1` to execute dynamic SQL. Can we see the SP in question?

Comment: @IvanStoev - the stored procedure does execute dynamic sql, but that procedure is not in my application and I don't have control over it. I have to call it. I will update the question with that important detail.

Comment: That's the real issue then, a nicely parameterized value can still cause injection if its (mis)used in dynamic SQL. The way to mitigate this depends on what validation logic you can apply to the input before sending it to the procedure & what the SP does with the value it receives. The responsibility for fixing this lies with the DBA/developer of the procedure.

Comment: Is the task to send in the dynamic part of the stored procedure as a parameter to the stored procedure?

Comment: @CodingYoshi - no. The input is a simple string.

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks. I thought/ was hoping there was some way to protect it from my side.

Comment: Define a *simple string* please.

Comment: Following @AlexK. 's comment, I have provided the information to the DBA, who has (following this proof) agreed to redo the stored procedure to use parameters in the dynamic sql rather than strings http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#good_practices. Really appreciate the input. Thank you.

Comment: You got a DBA to admit he's wrong. For that I salute you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following comments, I thought I should add a conclusion (Thank you @AlexK via comment).

If a stored procedure is written using non-parameterized dynamic sql, it is not possible for Entity Framework to protect it. This is not a fault of Entity Framework (which is, in general, very good at sql protection).

Should you find yourself in a similar situation, the stored procedure should be re-written using parameterised dynamic sql. A very good explanation can be found [here](http://sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#SQL_injection).

To Elaborate.

There is no way for Entity Framework to protect sql like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE search_orders @custid   nchar(5)     = NULL,
                               @shipname nvarchar(40) = NULL AS
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
SELECT @sql = ' SELECT OrderID, OrderDate, CustomerID, ShipName ' +
              ' FROM dbo.Orders WHERE 1 = 1 '
IF @custid IS NOT NULL
   SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND CustomerID LIKE ''' + @custid + ''''
IF @shipname IS NOT NULL
   SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND ShipName LIKE ''' + @shipname + ''''
EXEC(@sql)
```

But this will be safe:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE search_orders @custid   nchar(5) = NULL,
                               @shipname nvarchar(40) = NULL AS
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
SELECT @sql = ' SELECT OrderID, OrderDate, CustomerID, ShipName ' +
              ' FROM dbo.Orders WHERE 1 = 1 '
IF @custid IS NOT NULL
   SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND CustomerID LIKE @custid '
IF @shipname IS NOT NULL
   SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND ShipName LIKE @shipname '
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@custid nchar(5), @shipname nvarchar(40)',
                   @custid, @shipname
```

As far as I can tell, any of the code samples from the question would be valid 'safe' EF Code (though the extra work on the extension method would have been surplus to requirements).

**Update**

Following this, I contacted Microsoft and created a [PR](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/pull/1318), the basis of which has been accepted. The warning message on the official documentation is now [more detailed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql), hopefully reducing the chance of someone having the same problems.